# Text game problems in Python. Looping input prompt

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, input

So here's my next question with one of my student's code in his text based game. The idea is that in the game you can pick up an item and put it in a selected pocket. The problem is that when he runs this code he gets the prompt to pick a pocket to put the item in but then the input prompt just loops with the same question about where to put the item.

Ideas?

```
class grab():
    #Checks the player's pockets for items.
    def pocket_check(inventory, pocket, thing, input, state, list, room):
        if inventory[pocket] != None:
            print("You find that your %s is stuffed full.")%(input)
        if inventory[pocket] == None:
            inventory[pocket] = thing
            del room["Items"][thing]
            state["Strain"] += list[thing]["Weight"]
            print("You put the %s in your %s.")%(thing, input)

    #Takes items and putting them in the player's inventory
    def grab(inventory, thing, list, state, room):
        go = True
        while go:
            if list != "WEAPON" and state["Strain"]+list[thing]["Weight"] <= state["Strength"]:
                inp = input("Where will you put it?").lower()
                inp_broke = inp.split(" ")
                if inp_broke[0] == "stop":
                    go = False
                elif inp_broke[0] != "put":
                    inp = input("Where will you PUT it?").lower()
                    inp_broke = inp.split(" ")
                elif inp_broke[0] == "put":
                    if inp_broke[1:3] == "shirt pocket":
                        pocket_check(inventory, "Shirt Pocket", thing, "shirt pocket", state, list, room)
                    if inp_broke[1:4] == "left front pocket":
                        pocket_check(inventory, "Left Front Pocket", thing, "left front pocket", state, "ITEM", room)
                    if inp_broke[1:4] == "right front pocket":
                        pocket_check(inventory, "Right Front Pocket", thing, "right front pocket", state, "ITEM", room)
                    if inp_broke[1:3] == "back pocket":
                        pocket_check(inventory, "Back Pocket", thing, "back pocket", state, "ITEM", room)
```

Comment: Be careful when splitting on space: `inp.split(" ")`. Any (accidental) double space will result in an empty value in `inp_broke`. Use the default whitespace splitting instead: `inp_broke = inp.split()`.

Comment: You should encourage PEP 8 naming standards - like class names that start with a capital letter.

Comment: You should let the player use a coconut as a pocket. Then later give him a lime. Achievement Get: Put the lime in the coconut.

Comment: You can `break` out of the loop, instead of using `go = False` (and then your loop is simply `while True:`.  This is much more common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
if inp_broke[1:3] == "shirt pocket":
```

won't work. `inp_broke` is a list (of strings), and doesn't magically combine into a string.
You could use the `str.join` method:

```
if " ".join(inp_broke[1:3]) == "shirt pocket":
```

That will combine the separate items of the list into a string, separated by the initial string (in this case, a single space).

Comment: Still having issues. The changes you stated were made but it still returns to the top of the loop, stating, "Where will you put it". We put some print statements in to test to see if it was going through the whole function, which it was, but it would not progress past the end of the last elif statement.

Answer (score 0):

From your snippet:

```
np_broke = inp.split(" ")
...
if inp_broke[1:3] == "shirt pocket":
```

Slicing a list from a split() returns a list of string, not a string:

```
>>> inp = "put shirt pocket"
>>> inp_broke = inp.split(" ")
>>> inp_broke[1:3]
['shirt', 'pocket']
```

Answer (score 0):

`while go` will loop forever unless `False` is assigned to `go` within the loop.  The `pocket_check` method could return a boolean depending on its success and its return value assigned to `go` when called.